# the formula of eigenvalues of the matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

For the linear system of the ODEs$${x'= Ax}$$  can please anyone explain why the eigenvalues of the matrix A are given by
$$ {\displaystyle \lambda _{1,2}={\frac {\operatorname{tr} (A)\pm {\sqrt {\operatorname{tr} (A)^{2}-4~ \det(A)}}}{2}}.}$$

Answer (score 7):

This is true if $A$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix because the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $x^2 - \operatorname{tr}(A)x + \det(A)$. To see why, compute

$$ \left| \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} - xI \right| = \left| \begin{pmatrix} a - x & b \\ c & d - x \end{pmatrix} \right| = (a - x)(d - x) - bc = x^2 - (a + d)x + (ad - bc) \\ =
x^2 - \operatorname{tr}(A)x + \det(A). $$

Comment: thank you very much , and the same idea for n by n linear system ?

Comment: @user0533535412: Not really, the formula for the characteristic polynomial in terms of the matrix coefficients is much more complicated. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial for more details.